# Mailing list or websites for remote teaching positions in universities

Tags: teaching, job-search, online-learning, online-resource

I'm currently a part time math lecturer in an engineering college in France, but I'm very much willing to teach undergraduate level math courses outside France. However, despite searching on usual platforms like Indeed, LinkedIn I didn't find any such position.

I'm ideally looking to teach a course online, while remaining in France. I'm sure such possibilities exist but they're often not well advertised. So could you please suggest me some such websites or mailing lists where such jobs are advertised? It could be country-specific, and that's okay!

Comment: @Buffy It appears OP wants to teach remotely in a position that allows them to remain physically in France.

Answer (score 3):

[PolytechnicPositions.com](https://polytechnicpositions.com/) has a helpful mailing list of academic and faculty positions worldwide. But no idea whether you'll find a remote teaching opportunity. You may have to move and be prepared to teach in person to find an appointment.